# Ruby Encoding: Why Japanese text is not read as it is by scraper?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

> Actual HTML

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>綜合ユニコム株式会社</TITLE>
<a href=http://www.sogo-unicom.co.jp/index.html>綜合ユニコム株式会社</a>

</HTML>
```

> HTML received by rest-client get

```
 <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>�������j�R����������</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<a href=http://www.sogo-unicom.co.jp/index.html>�������j�R����������</a></font></td>
</HTML>
```

> Ruby code sample

```
 require 'rest-client'
 params_hash = {
          method: :get,
          url: 'http://sogo-uni.com/',
        }

response = RestClient::Request.execute(params_hash)
puts response.body
```

What is the reason that the scraper is not able to interpret Japanese langualge as it is?

Comment: Could you show us the code use to fetch that page?

Comment: Added the sample ruby snippet.

Comment: Try `puts response.body.encode('UTF-8', 'Shift_JIS')` – seems like rest client isn't able to determine the page's encoding automatically.

Comment: `puts response.body.encode('UTF-8', 'Shift_JIS')` is working. How about other languages? like Chinese, Korean ..etc ?

Comment: The default `puts response.body.encoding #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>`

Comment: What version of Ruby do you use?

Comment: `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 1):

Can you add in you `params_hash` the `content_type` attribute like below:

`content_type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8"`